# JS: styling windows.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of persons, and contact info button. I want to open popup window (about:blank) with the person's contact information. I straggled with two things.

**1)** if I clicked **person_1**, the info will be displayed. If i click again on the same person or another without closing the window, the window will not refresh itself and view the new info, it will just add it with the previous one. I solve this with...

```
if(info){info.document.body.innerHTML = '';}
```

the problem with this addition is now it's work fine on pc/chrome, but doesn't work on phones!
I tried with my phone it shows me empty page.

**2)** I'm displaying the contact info in Arabic which means the dir of the window should be from right to left. I can do that by add attribute to `html` tag or body `dir="rtl"` but I don't know how to do that, and how to style the window itself.

```
function contact(contact) {
    id  = $(contact).attr("id");
    contact_info = $('#contact'+id).val();

    info = window.open("", "info", "width=550,height=350");
    if(info){info.document.body.innerHTML = '';}    
    info.document.write(contact_info);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need

```
var info;

function contact(contact) {
    id  = $(contact).attr("id");
    contact_info = $('#contact'+id).val();
    open_window(contact_info, "Contact Info");
}

function open_window(content, title) {
try {
    if (info.closed) throw "reopen";
    info.document.body.innerHTML = '';
}catch (e) {
    info = window.open('', 'contact_info_window', 'width=550,height=350');
    info.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /><body></body>');
    info.document.body.dir = "rtl";
}
    info.document.title = title;
    info.document.write(content);
    info.focus();
}
```

Comment: it worked as I wanted ty, but any idea why this won't work on phones ?

Comment: Phones don't allow popups. You can use a link with target="_blank" to open a new tab, but you won't be able to use Javascript to control its contents. I'm pretty certain theres no way around that.

Comment: it worked on my iPhone, but the content display with safari chrome just empty popup window with no content

Comment: That's odd. All of the documentation I've read says it shouldn't pop up at all, and it also didn't pop up on my own iPhone. Either way, you still can't access the content of the popup using Javascript on an iPhone. That's why it shows up blank.